# Avoid warning 'Unreferenced Formal Parameter' with default argument

Tags: c++

This is my function

```
virtual int foo(bool status = false)
{
 return -1;
}
```

Compiler gives `warning C4100: 'iDispCompIndex': unreferenced formal parameter`

I would like to fix this by this way

```
virtual int foo(bool)
{
 return -1;
}
```

In this case is there a way to specify default value of the argument? because inherited classes may be need this

Comment: You can just cast it to `void` - `(void)status;`. In any case, overridden functions in derived classes will not inherit default arguments from the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way is to not name the parameter, just like you said:

```
virtual int foo(bool = false)
{
     return -1;
}
```

You can also deliberately ignore a value by casting it to `void`:

```
(void)status;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two options:

1) Use macro [UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163805.aspx)

2) Use #pragma to turn off warning for this exact part of code:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4100 )
virtual int foo(bool status = false)
{
 return -1;
}
#pragma warning( pop )
```

Comment: There are also (at least two) portable options that don't require weird Microsoftisms.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, yes, thank you. Solution with `virtual int foo(bool = false)` looks as ideal. And your second solution looks equal to macro UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER, but without any headers from Microsoft, so it is great too.